# Count how many words have the same beginning and ending letter/Python

Tags: python

> **QUESTION**: The variable sentence stores a string. Write code to
>   determine how many words in sentence start and end with the same
>   letter, including one-letter words. Store the result in the variable
>   same_letter_count.

I've tweaked this a few different ways but I still can't figure it out.  Any help + explanation is appreciated so I know how to handle this the next time.

```
sentence = "students flock to the arb for a variety of outdoor activities 
such as jogging and picnicking"

same_letter_count = 0
sentence_split = sentence.split(' ')
sent_length = len(sentence_split)
#print(sent_length)
# Write your code here.
for d in sentence_split:
    #print(d[0])
    if d[0] == d:
        same_letter_count = same_letter_count + 1
    elif d[-1] == d:
        same_letter_count = same_letter_count + 1
print(same_letter_count)
```

I'm getting an answer of 1, the correct answer is 2.

Comment: Hint: you need to be comparing `d[0]` with `d[-1]`.

Comment: You've only counted `a`.

Comment: Your main problem is that you compare a single letter to the entire word: `d[0] == d`.  The only way this can happen is if the word is a single letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact the Python's booleans can be treated like zeros and ones and just add up all the boolean values of the test `word[0] == word[-1]`. The expression:

```
[w[0] == w[-1] for w in sentence.split()]
```

evaluates to a list like `[True, False, False...]`. Taking the `sum` of that is the same as counting the number of `True` values and is a very typical way of doing something like this in Python.

```
sentence = "students flock to the arb for a variety of outdoor activities such as jogging and picnicking"
same_letter_count = sum(w[0] == w[-1] for w in sentence.split())
# 2
```

Comment: `sentence.split(" ")` => `sentence.split()` so no risk of empty fields.

Comment: Note that `sum(1 for w in sentence.split(' ') if w[0] == w[-1])` can be faster as the zeros aren't summed.

Comment: Thanks @DanD. that's a nice tip. For the purposes of the question, I'll probably leave it as-is just for clarity. But I'm filing that one away.

Answer (score 2):

```
if d[0] == d:
    same_letter_count = same_letter_count + 1
elif d[-1] == d:
    same_letter_count = same_letter_count + 1
```

This checks if the first letter is equal to the entire word, or if the last letter is equal to the entire word. Therefore you are only counting "a". Instead try

```
if d[0] == d[-1]:
    same_letter_count = same_letter_count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution by `pandas`:

```
s = pd.Series(sentence.split(' '))
(s.str[0] == s.str[-1]).sum()
```

gives answer `2`.

You can even get those words:

```
s[s.str[0] == s.str[-1]]
```

gives:

```
0    students
6           a
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "students flock to the arb for a variety of outdoor activities such as jogging and picnicking"
same_letter_count = 0

sentence_split = sentence.split(' ')
sentense_length = len(sentence_split)

for d in sentence_split:
    if d[0] == d[-1]:
        same_letter_count += 1
print(same_letter_count)
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer? Also, please format your code by placing it inside triple backticks or using the <code></code> tags